# how to print the no of letters including space in each element in list in python

Tags: python, list, printing, element, letter

so I making an app that prints the first letter and the no of words including space in each element in a list in python in the same line

so the list is a file which with the help of readlines() I have converted into a variable that can be used as a list
this is my code that can print the first letter of each element in that list so now I just have to print the no of letters in each element in the list I will provide my code, current output, expected output, and the file

```
    file = open("/usercode/files/books.txt", "r")

    #your code goes here
    contentlines = file.readlines()
    content = file.read()
    no_of_words = str(len(contentlines[0]))

    for first_letter in contentlines:
        print(first_letter[0])

    file.close()
```

current output

```
H
T
P
G
```

expected output

```
H12
T33
P18
D16
```

the file content

```
Harry Potter
The Red and the Black by Stendhal
Pride and Prejudice
David Copperfield
```

Comment: `no_of_words = str(len(contentlines[0]))` should be in for loop and printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of modification on your own code:

```py
file = open("books.txt", "r")

#your code goes here
contentlines = file.readlines()
content = file.read()

for line in contentlines:
  if line[-1] != "\n":
    no_of_words = len(line)-1
  else:
    no_of_words = len(line)
  print(line[0], no_of_words, sep="")

file.close()
```

##### Output

```
H12
T33
P19
D17
```

Note that, in the `len(line)-1`, the `-1` refers to the break line shown by "\n". It is counted as one character:

```py
myname = "\n"
print(len(myname))
```

This will output

```
1
```

Comment: ok so it was a sololearn code project but I used this code the problem was this was not the text file I wanted to use so I tried it with the other text file but it did not work so when checking I noticed that it was not reading the last line's last letter so before all of this code a opened the same file but in 'a' mode and I added a space to the last line so and then it worked and I already knew how to do this but I posted this question because I thought I don't know how to use this thank you

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can simplify your code to loop and print at the same time:

```
with open('/usercode/files/books.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        L = len(line.rstrip('\n'))
        print(f'{line[0]}{L}')
```

output:

```
H12
T33
P19
D17
```